# Kotlin object creation and memory management compared to Java

Tags: java, memory-management, kotlin

I've heard that in Kotlin creation of the new objects is cheap. How is Kotlin memory aspect of object creation is different from Java? Is there difference in cost of creating objects from the `data class` and `class`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you mean Kotlin targeting JVM, so I will tell you about this target.

Kotlin uses the same bytecode as Java, so performance in general is the same (some operations can be less or more optimized in Kotlin(thanks to compiler or stdlib) in compare to Java).

Data classes are just normal classes with additionally generated toString(), equals(), hashCode() and clone() methods, so they have the same performance as normal classes.

Comment: Is there really a different kind of JVM for Kotlin? Accroding to https://kotlinlang.org/ the available targets are JVM, Android (I guess Dalvik VM), JavaScript and native code via LLVM.  Also, the question was about memory costs, not about code performace.

Comment: Sorry, I meant JVM target for Kotlin. Objects uses the same amount of memory in comparison to the same objects in Java 

Comment: The question is about memory cost of creating a new object. In Java books, e.g. Bruce Eckel Thinking in Java, it's written that creating a new object is not an efficient process because the `new` places object on a heap. That's why Java has primitives. Kotlin does not have primitives and in Kotlin presentations I've heard Kotlin team saying that 'objects are cheap'. So I was wondering what is the difference

Comment: @Hiosdra how do you know that the Kotlin objects use the same amount of memory? Have you measured it?

Comment: Kotlin under the hood uses primitives everywhere it can (for Int, Long, Char etc.). For memory allocation it uses standard JVM instructions, so memory and time performance is the same as in Java

Comment: @Angelina I've made a simple benchmark, in which I used Epsilon GC [link](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/318) and benchamark do following: 1) declare linkedlist 2) add in for 1_000, 10_000, or 100_000 Integers and then print all of them (to not make compiler optimize it by deleting unused code) 3) print used memory
I made the same exact benchmark for Kotlin and Java (using Java Integers and Kotlin Ints) and results were the same for both languages

Comment: Regarding the initial statement, “*in Kotlin creation of the new objects is cheap*”, it is not wrong. You should just stay away from the conclusion that it was different than in Java. It’s just that in Java, creation of new objects is cheap too. At least with modern JVMs.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect no difference if Java and Kotlin are both compiled for same target VM - it should make no difference which source code produces the same bytecode.

As for `data class`, Hiosdra correctly [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53802008/1651361) that this is just a syntax sugar to tell the compiler to derive some standard methods useful for data-holding classes (see [the documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/data-classes.html)).